# What's the chromatic number of an open disk?

Tags: coloring

In the [Hadwiger-Nelson problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadwiger%E2%80%93Nelson_problem), any two points unit distance apart must have distinct colors. Does this problem become easier when we restrict ourselves to say, the points in the open disk of radius 1? What if we generalize this to open disks with radius $r$? At what radii does the chromatic number change? Obviously a lot of this is unknown since the Hadwiger-Nelson problem is unsolved, but I'm curious what *is* known.

Answer (score 1):

Little late to the question, but there was a paper a few years ago called "[*Triangles in the colored Euclidean plane*](http://www.ist.tugraz.at/files/publications/geometry/ap-tcep-19.pdf)" which tried something similar. Except they weren't thinking about it in terms of disks. They were just trying to just put together large patches of polygons with low chromatic numbers.

But I'm not entirely sure their coloring restriction is the same as in the Hadwiger-Nelson problem. But I had the same idea as you and after a bit of searching, this was the most relevant result that popped up.

Here's a relevant image from their paper:
[image]
And this looks like it'd be a 6-coloring of a disk of about raidus 1.07:
[image]

It's surprising there aren't any bigger 6-colorable discs that anyone has found yet.